# Linux swap partition not recognized on reboot

Tags: linux, swap

When I reboot my Linux server the swap space reads 0 in top.

- I am running a vanilla install of CentOS 5.2
- /etc/fstab looks fine from what I can tell

  ```
  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap swap defaults 0 0
  ```
- `swapon -a` returns "invalid params" error message for `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01`

Doing a `mkswap /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01` and then `swapon -a` works.

But each time I reboot the swap space goes back to 0 in top.

Comment: 1) Are you sure the error is "invalig params" not "invalid argument"? Don't retype manually, copy-paste everything. 2) Can you test whether reading from the logical volume is possible without errors (`dd if=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 bs=512 count=10 of=/dev/null`)?

Answer (score 6):

In `/etc/fstab`, all fields should be separated by whitespace. You have the last 2 fields' (fs_freq and fs_passno) values (zeros in both cases) separated by a comma.

Instead of this:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap swap defaults 0,0
```

You should have:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: nice spotting. I wouldn't have seen that immediately :)

Comment: I mistyped that line, it does not contain a comma.  I just confirmed this on the machine. (I edited the question.)

Answer (score 1):

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                   swap    defaults        0 0
```

-

```
# swapoff -a
# umount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01
# mount -a
```

then post the output.

Comment: # umount: /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01: not mounted

Comment: When I do swapon -a I get swapon: /dev/VolGroup00/Log01: Invalid argument

Comment: But doing a mkswap /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 and then swapon -a works.